# What does it mean: lancé à corps perdu dans une course-poursuite

Tags: traduction

In the recent headline of an article in Le Monde there is:

> Président Trump, an IV : Le candidat républicain, lancé à corps perdu
> dans une course-poursuite avec Joe Biden

I have trouble to understand "corps perdu" or "lost body" in this sentence.
Also, the verb lancer qc looks a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*À **corps perdu*** is an expression that indeed literaly translates to "at **lost body**".

It actually means something done without caring about damages that may affect the involved body, up to full lost.

There is at least another similar expression: *à **fonds perdus***, that means "done without caring about the induced cost / whatever the cost / knowing all money thrown to the project will be lost".

***Lancé*** means "in movement after having been launched". Note that the expression is *lancé **dans** une course poursuite*, i.e. more or less "running in a chasing race".

I might then translate that phrase that way:

> The republican candidate, engaged in a desperate chase against Joe Biden...

Comment: thanks, interesting directions of the translation, indeed desperate chase would capture the meaning of the action

Answer (score 3):

There is in this sentence a basic locution, "*à corps perdu*", which you can combine with picked verbs, here "*lancer*". We get the literal signification from the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corps) below.

> *Loc. adv. À corps perdu. **De toutes ses forces, avec une fougue que ne tempère pas la perspective de la fatigue, la crainte du danger**
>
> ex. : Se jeter, s'élancer à corps perdu dans la mêlée. Fatigué de s'en être tant donné, car les enfants font tout à corps perdu, il s'endormit*

You see from the definition that some of the picked verbs can be "lancer" and "s'élancer"; there are others verbs and other possibilities of combination : *dévaler (une pente,…)*, ; instead of using the locution as an adverbial modifier you can use it as an adjectival one : *une poursuite à corps perdu*,…

There is a figurative sense to this locution, to be found also in the TLFi.

> Fig. Avec passion, sans hésitation et sans mesure, sans retenue et sans prudence. Je me lance à corps perdu dans les lectures religieuses (Flaub., Corresp.,1846, p. 415).

In your sentence, this is of course the relevant sense. The verb used with it takes on also a figurative meaning. A translation of "*lancé à corps perdu*" would be (DeepL) "thrown with full body", (Harraps) *thrown recklessly*, *thrown without restraint*.

Comment: thanks, very helpful discussion, after reviewing my question and the answer, my confusion was also related to "lancer une course poursuite" - maybe there are other ways to catch up a race, hesitant, or without hopes, or maybe there are other ways to express this race without figurative sense